# Installing Linenoise for Perl6 on CentOS: cannot find library "luv"

Tags: centos, raku

I'm trying to install Linenoise for zef in perl6.

```
user@centos:/illumina/runs/Scripts/perl6/zef$ sudo bin/zef install Linenoise --force-build
===> Searching for: Linenoise
===> Searching for missing dependencies: LibraryMake
===> Searching for missing dependencies: Shell::Command
===> Searching for missing dependencies: File::Which, File::Find
===> Building: Linenoise:ver<0.1.1>:auth<Rob Hoelz>
/bin/ld: cannot find -luv
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/root/.zef/store/p6-linenoise.git/480fd919b2c082e691c518fd50c19ad8719532b6/resources/libraries/liblinenoise.so] Error 1
```

I don't know how to locate and install this library "-luv".  I cannot find information on internet search engines.

I've tried `yum search` & `yum search all` and I can't find out how to install this.

Comment: My first guess is that's something to do with libuv. I'm investigating.

Comment: @raiph The solution on CentOS is `sudo yum install libuv.x86_64 libuv-devel.x86_64 libuv-static.x86_64` if you put this down as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: \o/ It's considered perfectly cromulent to answer your own questions on SO and accept your answers too. You asked a legitimate question. You found a spot on answer. I'll do the answer if you prefer but I would love to see your answer it yourself and just mention me in the answer for giving you the key hint. Whodda thunk that negative luv was about yum lib? :) But if you'd rather save time that's fine too and I'll write it up later. Your choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is simple

`sudo yum install libuv.x86_64 libuv-devel.x86_64 libuv-static.x86_64`

the issue was that if `libuv` isn't installed, it gives an error with `-luv` which doesn't really help me know what library I need. @raiph gave me the hint I needed

Comment: Hi again con. I posted [an issue about this at the Linenoise repo](https://github.com/hoelzro/p6-linenoise/issues/28) noting that "-luv" was cryptic. The creator/maintainer, a wonderful fellow Rob Hoelzro, responded a day later saying "I spun up a little VM with CentOS 7 to try to reproduce this - no dice, unfortunately. However, I have a theory" which he explained but concluded "Unfortunately, without knowing more about how the user installed Rakudo, there's not much more I can do!". If you could post a comment there to either help take a look or say you don't have time that would be helpful.

Comment: Thx @con. FYI, Rob has replied asking for a couple bits of info. I think it's important that we try get to the bottom of what went wrong but maybe it isn't. You and Rob should only spend more than a few more minutes on it if you both think it makes sense to do so. TIA for whatever you do.